# Kendo UI sortable widget's change event not firing in touch devices while using Chrome browser

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, kendo-ui, touch-event

I am developing a web application using AngularJS. There is a requirement like, a user should be able to sort a list of Items and to save that sorted order for future reference. For this particular purpose I used a **Kendo UI Sortable** Widget. The widget is working as expected in normal devices. But the sorting is not working in *MS windows 10* devices with latest chrome, if I am using fingers to drag and drop the items.(Mouse drag and drop is working) The major thing is that the Kendo UI Sortable widget's change event not firing in this particular situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a latest chrome version issue after the introduction of pointer events. Please check following links.

1. https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/492
2. https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/457